# Implementation of URL.openConnection() so that it can be casted

Tags: java, casting, abstract-class

I don't understand why an abstract class can be casted to any of its subclasses.
For exemple:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
HttpURLConnection httpURL = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I've noticed that openConnection() returns an URLConnection instance, which is an abstract class. How could it be implemented (using a simpler example) so that it could be casted to a subclass?

For Example, if I had:

```
abstract class C1
{
    abstract void f1();
    abstract void f2();
}

class C2 extends C1
{
    @Override
    void f1() {
        System.out.println("f12");
    }

    @Override
    void f2() {
        System.out.println("f22");
    }

    void f3() {
        System.out.println("f32");
    }
}

class C3 extends C1 {
    @Override
    void f1() {
        System.out.println("f13");
    }

    @Override
    void f2() {
        System.out.println("f23");
    }

    void f3() {
        System.out.println("f33");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       C2 c2 = new C2();
       C3 c3 = new C3();
       C1 c1 = c3;

       c3 = (C3) c1;
       c2 = (C2) c1;
    }
}
```

then c3 = (C3) c1; would work, but the second cast wouldn't (thing that I understand in this situation).

So how could we know if openConnection() returns the right subclass (so that it doesn't cause a runtime exception when casted)? I assume the form of the returned object could be:

```
return (URLConnection) obj;
```

where obj is declared as HttpUrlConnection or JarURLConnection.

Or return some obj that is declared using a lambda expression or anonymous method (without casting).

**UPDATE:**

```
JarURLConnection hpCon = (JarURLConnection) hp.openConnection();
```

would actually cause a runtime exception: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.JarURLConnection"

Why is openConnection() returning URLConnection then if it's actually a HttpURLConnection and casting to JarURLConnection would fail?

Answer (score 1):

Your example will result on ClassCastException at runtime, since c1 is not of type c2.

Down-casting: going from an super class to a implementation is unsafe, so that's why you need to explicit cast it with (C3), while upercasting (going from C3 to C1) is safe and you don't need to type it.

What happened to your code is that you erased the old type and tryed to reasign with a explicit cast that will cause a ClassCastException (from C3 to C2) at Runtime.

Note for example the following would not be compilable:

```
 C3 c3 = (C3) new C2();
```

While this does (but crash on runtime):

```
 C3 c3 = (C3) (C1) new C2();
```

The sample of URLConnection works cause openConnection DOES return a instance of HttpUrlConnection but still need a unsafe cast to its type. Note that Http*s*UrlConnection can be returned from the openConnection, but since it extends HttpUrlConnection it can be casted as it.

Comment: You mean that in the function we have an HttpsUrlConnection object, and when we return it we: return (UrlConnection) httpUrl; ? But what if that was a JarURLConnection? I just don't get how it chooses between them inside the function

Comment: Pseudocode: if (url.protocol == http) return new HttpUrlConnection(); if (url.protocol == https) return new HttpsUrlConnection(); if (url.protocol == jar) return new JarUrlConnection();. As simple as that (in principle. In reality the process is a bit more complex)

Comment: Factory Pattern, with a [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) thrown into the mix. See also [`URLStreamHandlerFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java support two types of casting

- Upcasting    -  Casting instance of sub class in class hierarchy to one of its super class
- Downcasting  -  Casting super class reference to its sub class instance type in the class hierarchy.

***Thumb Rule***

- Class hierarchy starts from instance type to its super class type
- Unrelated classes cannot be casted

In your example

- Class C3 is subclass and Class C1 is its super Class (Hierarchy : C3 -> C1 -> Object)
- Class C2 is subclass and Class C1 is its super Class (Hierarchy : C2 -> C1 -> Object)
- Class C1 (Hierarchy : C1 -> Object)
- Class C3 and C2 are not related
- Class C1 is not related to C2 and C3

C1 c1 = c3; (**Valid**. It is a upcast. Instance type of sub class C3 is assigned to its super class type c1)

 *Now c1 is referencing an instance of its sub type C3. It can be casted to its instance type or to any if its super types*

c3 = (C3) c1; (**Valid**. It is a downcast. Reference type C1 is casted to its instance type C3)

c2 = (C2) c1; (**Invalid**. Trying to Cast instance of C3 to an unrelated class type C2)

c3 = (C3)(new C1()) (**Invalid**. C1 is not related to C3)

c2 = (C2)(new C1()) (**Invalid**. C1 is not related to C2)